# PHP loop: Add a div around every three items syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I'm using a loop in wordpress to output posts. I want to wrap every three posts inside of a div. I want to use a counter to increment on each iteration of the loop but I'm not sure of the syntax that says "if $i is a multiple of 3" or "if $i is a multiple of 3 - 1".

```
$i = 1;
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     // If is the first post, third post etc.
     if("$i is a multiple of 3-1") {echo '<div>';}

     // post stuff...

     // if is the 3rd post, 6th post etc
     if("$i is a multiple of 3") {echo '</div>';}

$i++; endwhile; endif;
```

How do I make this happen? thanks!

Comment: What happens if I would like to added only if it is more than 3 items? and when it equals to 3 items leave it without changes?

Comment: This was the easiest way I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Why not do the following? This will open it and close it after the third post. Then close the ending div in the event there is not a multiple of 3 to display.

```
$i = 1;
//added before to ensure it gets opened
echo '<div>';
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     // post stuff...

     // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
     if($i % 3 == 0) {echo '</div><div>';}

$i++; endwhile; endif;
//make sure open div is closed
echo '</div>';
```

In case you didn't know, `%` is the modus operator will return the remainder after the two numbers are divided.

Comment: that looks good-- is there an advantage to using one or the other in terms of speed or efficiency? I think using the modulus operator makes one less line of code

Comment: i understand now-- using the modulus will create an unclosed div if there is no multiple of 3. Thank you!

Comment: I like this better more so because it make sure to close all of the opening `divs`. What I would actually do is take the first div and echo it outside the loop. That way even if there is only 1 you have a open/close tag. This will make sure you don't kill the formatting. The actually processing of it should not affect speeds at all since it is a "basic" equation.

Comment: Something that might help others remove the empty first tag (or last?) is changing `$i % 3 == 0` to `$i !== 0 && $i % 3 == 0` this does exactly the same thing but makes sure that we do not check the first id.

Comment: You save my lot of time, i appreciate you +1

Comment: You should also check the length of `$wp_query->post_count` because if it equals `$i` and `$i % 3 == 0` than you wouldn't want to output `</div><div>` since it would be an empty div at the end of your html.  Just a FYI.

Comment: What Solomon says. The perfect if-construct is `if ($i !== 0 && $i % 3 === 0 && $i !== $the_query->post_count)`.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
if ( $i % 3 == 0 )
```

In your code you can use:

```
if($i % 3 == 2) {echo '<div>';}
```

and

```
if($i % 3 == 0) {echo '</div>';}
```

Comment: could you please help me put that in the context of the code I pasted in my answer above?

Comment: @j-man86: you can use it has-is, replace `"$i is a multiple of 3-1"` with `$i % 3 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1;
$post_count=$wp_query->found_posts;
//added before to ensure it gets opened
echo '<div>';
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     // post stuff...

     // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
     if($i % 3 == 0 && $i != $post_count) {echo '</div><div>';} elseif($i % 3 == 0 && $i == $post_count){echo '</div>';}

$i++; endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: it would be better if you include some explanation about your code.

Comment: The above selected answer was adding an extra div, I gave solution to that, the code I pasted don't add any extra div

Comment: I wanted to add this code as comment but my reputation is below 50.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need extra div you can use this :

```
 $i = 0;

 $post_count = $wp_query->found_posts;

 if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :$wp_query->the_post();

 // If is the first post, third post etc.
 ( ($i%3) == 0 ) ? echo '<div>' : echo '';

 // post stuff...

 // if is the 3rd post, 6th post etc or after the last element

( $i == ($post_count - 1) || (++$i%3) == 0 )  ? echo '</div>' : 
echo '';

endwhile; endif;
```