# Wordpress: div enclosing each group of three posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In Wordpress, I want to have a div wrapping around every three posts (because the posts are in a grid, three per line, and I want each line to have a uniform height so the "read more" buttons line up at the bottom - http://restartcomputer.com/category/products/mac-products/). I figured out (logically) how to do this - it is basically outlined in the accepted answer of this question: [PHP loop: Add a div around every three items syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947878/php-loop-add-a-div-around-every-three-items-syntax)

However, I've tried everything and cannot get the code to work. The divs do not get added, at all. Here is the code:

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    $counter = 1; ?>
    <div class="entries-wrapper">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        //post stuff

        <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0) { ?>
            </div><div class="entries-wrapper">
        <?php }
        $counter += 1; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    //some more code

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: seems everything fine: are you sure you're editing the right template file? try this: add some text at the end of your code, outside any `if` condition... if it shows up on the page than it's alright

Comment: @d79 Bingo!! There are a lot of unused files in this template, which I inherited from another team of designers. I was editing one very similar to the one I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have not entered back into Script (Line 4):

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    $counter = 1; ?>
    <div class="entries-wrapper">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        //post stuff

        <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0) { ?>
            </div><div class="entries-wrapper">
        <?php }
        $counter += 1; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    //some more code

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I did something similar in my theme to align posts side by side:

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php $col = 1; ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php if($col == 1) echo "<div class='row'>"; ?>
                        <div class="post col<?php echo $col; ?>" id="post-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
                        <?php
                                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                                 */
                                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                        ?>
                        <?php (($col==1)?$col=2:$col=1); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($col == 1) echo "</div>"; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>


                <?php kubrick_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
```

Can also try moving the DIV within the WHILE statement.

Comment: Thanks very much for catching that. I had, in fact, forgotten to enter back into the script; however, I made that change and the entries-wrapper divs are still not showing up! Any other ideas?