# Different size grid with specific order PHP

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I need to make a grid similar to this:

**Few keywords:** specific size pattern, bigger points in higher.

[image]

---

**All boxes are custom posts - lets call every box a post.**

All different sizes posts have different meta_key called `$size`:

- Yellow/big `$size= 1;`
- Orange/medium `$size= 2;`
- Blue/small `$size= 3;`

---

All posts have also meta_key value called `$points` which are totally different for each (can be anything from 0 to 10000). `$points` is currently used as orderby.

This is how I call all these posts:

```
$custom_posts= new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'custom-post', 
      'meta_key' => 'points', 
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
)); 

if ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) :


echo '<div id="post-items"><ul class="row list-unstyled">';

while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post();

$size= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_size', true );
$points = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_points', true );



echo '<li>';


if($size == 1) {
?>
      //Big yellow box HTML
<?php
}
else if($size == 2) {
    ?>
      //Medium orange box HTML
    <?php
}
else if($size == 3) {
    ?>
      //Small blue box HTML
    <?php
}
echo '</li>';

endwhile;

echo '</ul></div>';

wp_reset_query();

else :
?>
<p class="text-muted"><?php _e( 'No Posts.', 'aa' ); ?></p>
<?php
endif;
```

---

**QUESTION:**

Any ideas how to query them in specific `$size` pattern also considering `$points` (higher points in higher, but do not break the order - *LIKE ON MY IMAGE*)?

Im working my arse off as we speak (it's 3rd day now on this problem!!) & I would appriciate every idea, comment or source!

---

What could be useful but I haven't found a working solution yet (I'll add more if I come across some):

Using modulus:
[PHP loop: Add a div around every three items syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947878/php-loop-add-a-div-around-every-three-items-syntax)

---

**UPDATE 1:**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "query them in specific $size pattern also considering $points (higher points in higher, but do not break the order - LIKE ON MY IMAGE)?". Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Mike Im sorry if that seems a bit confusing - I was having trouble expaining myself. I want my posts be in specific pattern considering the size (same as on image) but order them with points inside that pattern. All orange boxes are ordered by points but stay where all orange boxes are, also there's 2 big yellow boxes; even if the yellow box below has more points, they switch places but still both yellow boxes stay at specific spot considering the whole size pattern. I can try to clarify even more if it's needed. Let me know. I might even do another image.

Comment: @Mike Basically the `$point` competition/orderby works only within same size boxes - size pattern is always the same.

Comment: I *think* I know what you mean, but I'm not sure. Can you just `ORDER BY points` and then use a `switch` to get the size when you loop over the results since we know the pattern should be 1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3?

Comment: @Mike Im pretty sure (99%) you got the point. I would appriciate & short integration of your suggestion with my query code because Im not that sure where or how to add `switch` (not that good yet). **Now the even more tricky part:** What if there's  `unknown` amount of posts & it still works? Repeat the pattern somehow?

Comment: Might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0egfd5LwU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Wordpress expert by any stretch, so there may be an easier way to do this with a `foreach` loop, but here it is with a `while` as you have it in the question:

```
// This will be used as a counter
$i=0;
while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    // Get size based on counter
    switch($i) {
        case 0:
        case 5:
            $size = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            $size = 2;
            break;
        default:
            $size = 3;
    }
    $points = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_points', true );



    echo '<li>';


    if($size == 1) {
    ?>
        //Big yellow box HTML
    <?php
    }
    else if($size == 2) {
        ?>
        //Medium orange box HTML
        <?php
    }
    else if($size == 3) {
        ?>
        //Small blue box HTML
        <?php
    }
    echo '</li>';
    // Increment the counter
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

If I understand your question correctly, this should always display the sizes in the order that you have them (1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3, etc.). Also, if there are less than that number of entries, it will still work, and if there are more, size 3 is the default, so anything else after this will display as 3.

Comment: Let me know if you want this pattern to *repeat* instead of making everything after this size 3 if we have more entries than what is in your question.

Comment: Note, this answer will *not* use any "filler" divs as you have in your question. Instead it shifts everything up.

Comment: Thanks Mike!! I'll try it out  as soon as I finish watching a tutorial video. About shifting everything up, Im not sure that I understand.. What does it do with different size divs if something is missing from the center of grid? Also I would be very grateful if you also added a `different version of code` or `notes of changes` (without deleting current version) in order to repeat the pattern so that I could experiment. My ultimate goal is that blue/small posts are not in repeatable pattern & are always last / at the end.

Comment: There isn't really a whole lot to annotate. All I did was add the counter and the `switch` to get the size instead of using the database. There will never be anything missing in the middle using this method.

Comment: I just tried it out & now I see.. Basically you give the `$size` according to orderby count number of that post.. Unfortunately this is not what Im looking for. It's important that every post has meta_key `$size` in database & that query will place them accordingly..