# PHP loop: Add a div with different class around every three items syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to create a loop for my posts which wraps a  and class to every three posts group. The tricky part is that there are 3 different classes which need to keep looping.

So, basically it should create a div with a class of "right" wrapping around the first 3 posts and then a second div with a class of "left" wrapping around the next 3 and a third div wrapping around the next 3 ones after that.

This pattern needs to repeat as the posts go on.

It will look something like this:

```
<div class="right">
  <div>Post 1</div>
  <div>Post 2</div>
  <div>Post 3</div>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <div>Post 4</div>
  <div>Post 5</div>
  <div>Post 6</div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <div>Post 7</div>
  <div>Post 8</div>
  <div>Post 9</div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

And repeat

Ive tried this: [PHP loop: Add a div around every three items syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947878/php-loop-add-a-div-around-every-three-items-syntax) But its only adding the first class and then repeating the second class.

Comment: post your code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the reference answer you linked to fit according to your requirement.

**Original answer:** [PHP loop: Add a div around every three items syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947999/7198013)

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $j = 0;
    $target_class = array( 'right', 'left', 'middle' );

    //added before to ensure it gets opened
    echo '<div class="'.$target_class[$j].'">';
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();


         // Do whatever you want here.


         // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
         if($i % 3 == 0) {
            // echo inner div if target class is not right
            echo ( $j != 0 ? '<div class="inner-div"></div>' : '' );
            // send back to first position if it goes above the third position
            $k = ( ++$j == 3 ? 0 : $j );
            echo '</div><div class="'.$target_class[$k].'">';}

    $i++; endwhile; endif;
    //make sure open div is closed
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

This should work. Did not test it though.

**Edit:** Tested and fixed. Code is working

**Edit: 2** Update code to entertain request from comment.

**Edit: 3** Update code to entertain request from comment.

Comment: Hi @shazyriver, yes it did thanks so much! Any way I can modify this to add a div inside the left and middle div's? Fairly new to php, forgive me if I'm asking a silly question.

Comment: Of course you can. Updated the code for that @LadyX and please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but it doesn't reflect yet. I've updated the code to show you what I mean with the extra div inside.

Comment: This is weird. It usually shows accept right away. Anyways, i have edited the code again it should do what you want. @LadyX

Comment: Thanks so much! I see it says only reputation of 15 and up is recorded

Comment: @LadyX i see. You are upvoting it. Please click on the check under that. See here for visual https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235